# Why do c++ I/O streams have a conversion operator to void*?

Tags: c++, iostream, conversion-operator

I accidentally called `operator delete[]` on a `ifstream` object, instead of on a file name. I expected the compiler to issue an error because `delete[]` only operates on pointers, not objects. However, the compiler didn't complain (not even a warning).

When debugging this, I saw that the system calls `operator void*` on the object. Surprisingly, this doesn't even crash ([demo](http://ideone.com/M2hF3G)).

So I wonder: why does this operator exists in first place?

Is it needed to support the `if (!file)` syntax? If yes, why not convert it to a safe-bool or use an `explicit operator bool` instead?

Comment: This has been changed in C++11.

Comment: "why not use an `explicit operator bool` instead?" That's exactly what C++11 specifies.

Comment: The bigger problem is that you use `new[]` and `delete[]`. Quality of the code is inversely proportional to the count of `new`/`delete` and `new[]`/`delete[]` in it.